# Drupal 6.37 to 8.2.x upgrade with drush fails with 1115 Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'

Tags: 8, drush, upgrading

I am upgrading a legacy Drupal 6.37 site running on mysql 5.1 to a fresh install of Drupal 8.2.1 with mysql 5.7.16 on a remote host.  I have installed the migration modules required for drush and am able to execute the following:

```
drush migrate-upgrade
--legacy-db-url=mysql://root:XXXXXXXXXX@172.172.172.172/drupal_db
--legacy-root=http://www.currentsite.com --configure-only
```

but I am getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1115 Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'
```

I am aware of the `'_dsn_utf8_fallback' => TRUE,` connection setting and have included that parameter in my connection section of `settings.php` on the new host, but I am still getting the same error.